# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Carousel>' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I encountered a warning while working with the Carousel Slider library I checked but could not find the cause Thank you for helping me find my problem
I put the classes that could have caused this warning here and below
Thank you all

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:multi_shop/model/carousel.dart';

class RemoteService {
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future<dynamic> fetchCarouselData() async {
    try{
      final response = await client.get(
        Uri.parse('https://my-shop.com/home-carousels'),
      );
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        return carouselFromJson(response.body);
      }
      return null;
    } catch(e){
      return null;
    }
  }
}


import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:multi_shop/http/remote_services.dart';
import 'package:multi_shop/model/carousel.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController{
  var box = GetStorage();
  var isLoading = false;
  List<Carousel> carouselData = [];

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchCarousel();
    if(box.read('carouselData') != null) {
      carouselData.assignAll(box.read('carouselData'));
    }
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchCarousel() async {
    try{
      isLoading = true;
      update();
      List<Carousel> data = await RemoteService.fetchCarouselData();
      carouselData.assignAll(data);
      box.write('carouselData', data);
    }finally{
      isLoading = false;
      update();
      print('data fetch done');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't show us the entire relevant code, *e.g.* the definition of `carouselFromJson`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not `type safety`,

- do not use `dynamic` if you already have `Carousel` type;
- return empty array instead of `null`;

I would refactor your code as

```dart
static Future<List<Carousel>> fetchCarouselData() async {
    try{
      final response = await client.get(
        Uri.parse('https://my-shop.com/home-carousels'),
      );
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        return carouselFromJson(response.body);
      }
      return [];
    } catch(e){
      return [];
    }
  }
```

And please, do not call async code inside `onInit()`, use `onReady()` for async stuff, read comments of these methods for more.

For more enhancement I would recommend use [fluent_result](https://pub.dev/packages/fluent_result) to deal better with exceptions and errors in the code.